# How http3 is reducing response time on slow connection?

Tags: http2, http3

[image]HTTP/3 (Quic) is advertised as it reduces round trip time by using UDP instead of TCP. In theory, it reduces response time on slow connections (high latency). When I take a test on my computer, I see nearly no difference. Am I making a mistake or which tool to use to see a difference?

I have two servers in the same country which have roughly 50ms latency on a regular cable connection. I use Chrome / Dev Tools -> Network Throttling.

In theory, http3 should be faster on a 3G and Slow 4G connections but it is not.

Cable Connection:
HTTP2: ~50ms
HTTP3: ~50ms

Fast 3G:
HTTP2: ~585ms
HTTP3: ~565ms

4G Slow:
HTTP2: ~155ms
HTTP3: ~155ms

4G Regular:
HTTP2: ~55ms
HTTP3: ~55ms